# How to word wrap text in HTML?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

How can text like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` which exceeds the width of a `div` (say `200px`) be wrapped?

I am open to any kind of solution such as CSS, jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Try this:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Am I mistaken or word-wrap is a CSS3 propriety?

Comment: It's CSS3, but it works in almost all mainstream browsers, including IE5.5 -> 9 - http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Comment: When word-wrap: break-word; doesn't work try word-break: break-all; /*this one is a killer*/

Comment: @redochka But when using `word-break: break-all;` then in normal text it breaks words in the middle, which is ugly... Can't we have a mix of both behaviors ?

Comment: **Important:** It is `word-break: break-all` and not `word-wrap: break-all`. Easy mistake to make

Comment: `word-break: break-word` gave me the functionality I wanted. It breaks long words to new lines, but also prevents formatting (like container width) from being broken. Using `word-break: break-all` only does the latter.

Answer (score 69):

On bootstrap 3, make sure the white-space is not set as 'nowrap'.

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Great. I tried using word-break: break-all on a Twitter Bootstrap 3 panel body but it never worked. Adding white-space:normal was the fix.

Comment: Nice, I needed `white-space: normal;` too before it worked.

Answer (score 60):

You can use a soft hyphen like so:

`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&shy;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

This will appear as

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

if the containing box isn't big enough, or as

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

if it is.

Comment: But how will you know where to put the `&shy;`?

Comment: You put it into long words where they may be split. You can even get that information automatically from a suitable dictionary.

Comment: But how about gibberish like the one in the example? Is it ok to turn `aaaaaa...aaaaa` into `a&shy;a&shy;a&shy;a&shy;a&shy;a&shy;a...a&shy;a&shy;a&shy;a`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I like that it's too shy to do anything until it has to ;-)

Comment: this works fine if the word to be wrapped is an overly.long.java.package.name or some similar string with many dots. then you can add the &shy; after each dot.

Comment: this is a poor approach in today responsive websites.

Comment: I like this. No need for a stupid css when I am using this in debug text printed by a php script

Answer (score 29):

```css
div {
    /* Set a width for element */
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

The '`word-wrap`' solution only works in IE and browsers supporting `CSS3`.

The best cross browser solution is to use your server side language (php or whatever) to locate long strings and place inside them in regular intervals the html entity `&#8203;`
This entity breaks the long words nicely, and works on all browsers.

e.g.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#8203;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: "place inside them in regular intervals the html entity #8203" but then when you try to copy the text and paste it somewhere, you'll have a random Unicode character in the middle

Answer (score 10):

The only one that works across IE, Firefox, chrome, safari and opera if there are no spaces in the word (such as a long URL) is:

```
div{
    width: 200px;  
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

I found this to be bullet-proof.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me

```
word-wrap: normal;
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: 3px auto;
line-height: 1.4;
-webkit-line-clamp: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Comment: Loved this approach. covered all bases. thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Another option is also using:

```
div
{
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This will set all your div elements in all browsers that support **CSS1** (which is pretty much all common browsers as far back as IE 8)

Comment: If you have a `<pre>` element you want to have word wrapping, this works and `word-break` or `word-wrap` don't.

Answer (score 4):

[Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241448/926460)

```
.wrap
{
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */    
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */    
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */    
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p style="word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;">
    Adsdbjf bfsi hisfsifisfsifs shifhsifsifhis aifoweooweoweweof
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS property -

```
overflow-wrap: anywhere;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to the paragraph.

```css
width:420px; 
min-height:15px; 
height:auto!important; 
color:#666; 
padding: 1%; 
font-size: 14px; 
font-weight: normal;
word-wrap: break-word; 
text-align: left;
```

Comment: I like `text-overflow:ellipsis` as much as the next guy, but it is not a correct answer to this question. He's looking to word wrap, not truncate the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Example from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/):

```css
div {
    -ms-word-break: break-all;

    /* Be VERY careful with this, breaks normal words wh_erever */
    word-break: break-all;

    /* Non standard for webkit */
    word-break: break-word;

    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

More examples [here](https://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/).

Answer (score 1):

In HTML body try:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 800px">
                Hello world, how are you? More text here to see if it wraps after a long while of writing and it does on Firefox but I have not tested it on Chrome yet. It also works wonders if you have a medium to long paragraph. Just avoid writing in the CSS file that the words have to break-all, that's a small tip.
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In CSS body try:

```
background-size: auto;

table-layout: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
div{
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

the property text-overflow: ellipsis add ... and line-clamp show the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have used bootstrap. 
My html code looks like ..

```
<div class="container mt-3" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 wrap-text">
      <h6>
        text content
      </h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap-text {
     text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap has `text-justify` class, so you can use it instead of `.wrap-text`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this **CSS**

```
p {
  width: min-content;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

The overflow-wrap CSS property applies to inline elements, setting whether the browser should insert line breaks within an otherwise unbreakable string to prevent text from overflowing its line box

```
overflow-wrap: anywhere | break-word
```

check details in the demo in above link.

Answer (score -1):

A server side solution that works for me is: `$message = wordwrap($message, 50, "<br>", true);` where `$message` is a string variable containing the word/chars to be broken up. 50 is the max length of any given segment, and `"<br>"` is the text you want to be inserted every (50) chars.

Comment: This solution will not work if 50 times the character width is more than the required maximum of 200px. Just use your browser's zooming function and you'll eventually see it break...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
div {display: inline;}
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score -4):

Use `word-wrap:break-word` attribute along with required width. Mainly, put 
**the width in pixels, not in percentages.**

```
width: 200px;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: This is identical to the answer above. Why bother?