# text wrapping for one long word

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i make a text wrap inside a div so that even one long **word** will be wrapped not only nicely spaced words? do i need js to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to word wrap text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style=”word-wrap: break-word”>Here is some content for the div element</div>
```

found similar question: [How to word wrap text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html)

References:

http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/

http://www.1keydata.com/css-tutorial/wrap.php

http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/627827-how-wrap-text-css

Answer (score 0):

using css you can achieve

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Style

```
div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `word-wrap: break-word;` in your css for the div.