# Django and wrap lines problem

Tags: python, django

I've a problem from many years.

The problem is a long text not separated by white spaces in a div. No wrap is applied and it breaks all layout.

How can I fix in django in a good way?

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example? Code?

Comment: What are you expecting or wanting from Django?  I ask because this seems like an html/css question rather than python/django.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand the question it is HTML-side problem, not django-side.  For HTML solution look [How to word wrap text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html).  If you still want to wrap text in python code, [textwrap.wrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) will help you.

Also there is convenient template tag for this: [wordwrap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#wordwrap).  It uses [django.utils.text.wrap](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/text.py#L25) function which seems more suitable for using in Django projects.

Comment: Yes, this has nothing at all to do with Django. It's a HTML/CSS question.

Answer (score 8):

This was bugging me as the built-in word-wrap template tag should have just worked. Instead use this...

```
{{ value|wordwrap:50|linebreaksbr }}
```

or

```
{{ value|wordwrap:50|linebreaks }}
```

depending if you want `<br>` or `<br> and <p>` tags

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps, but an approach could be creating a new filter based on `truncatewords` filter.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords

Code looks very simple:

```
def truncate_filter(value, maxlen):
    if len(value) <= maxlen:
        return value
    return value[:maxlen-2] + '..'
```

Another ideia is using: `{{ username|stringformat:".10s" }}` to truncate in 10 characters.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat