# How do I make a text go onto the next line if it overflows?

Tags: css

I tried `word-wrap: break-word;`, but it separates lines mid word.

Comment: Have you tried setting max-width on the containing div?

Comment: Maybe it separates the line mid word because you set it to `break-word`, what did you expected that to do? Have you check what other options `word-wrap` has?

Comment: This is the default behavior in most contexts. Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to word wrap text in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html)

Comment: word-break: break-all;

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As long as you specify a width on the element, it should wrap itself without needing anything else.

Comment: The error was that it was part of a pre element. Once I changed pre to p this answer worked.

Comment: What happens if you set the `width: auto`? My button's text still gets cut off at the right edge of it's parent container. Any ideas?

Comment: @andystructible That's probably going to be hard to answer, lacking context (what other styles are applied to it). I'd suggest opening a new question. One possibility is that at some point `overflow: hidden` was applied to the button, or the button is not in the document flow (if, for instance, it's been floated).

Comment: If the text doesn't wrap by itself the problem may be that you have `white-space: nowrap;` somewhere in the styles.

Comment: thanks @Velimir that one was the solution for mine

Comment: @Velimir Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 102):

In order to use `word-wrap: break-word`, you need to set a width (in px). For example:

```
div {
    width: 250px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

word-wrap is a CSS3 property, but it should work in all browsers, including IE 5.5-9.

Comment: It also works for width in in (inches)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saved a whole lot of headache for me, when i was trying to set the width on a datalist which is using a label control to display multi-line text content..Once again, thanks.

Comment: It also works for percentages of width in React

Answer (score 16):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

add this to your container
that should do the trick