# Push the word to new line with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the the following scenario where i need to push the entire word to the new line if it exceeds the width of the box. i have used CSS3 ***word-wrap*** property to achieve this. but it breaks the word as shown below.

[image]

I would like not to break a word and push the entire word to the next line if the text is more.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="img-container">   
        <img class="img-icon" src="/icons/image1.png">  
    </div>
   <p class="icon-footer">Performance Validator</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container img-container {
    display: flex;
}
.container .img-container .img-icon {
    border:1px solid #000;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    outline: 0;
}
.icon-footer {
    margin: 0;
    width: 64px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369819/how-do-i-make-a-text-go-onto-the-next-line-if-it-overflows), you could remove the word-wrap itself

```
.icon-footer {
    margin: 0;
    width: 64px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it without using `word-wrap: break-word` property. By default the word will overflow out of the parent container which is the default property.

`word-wrap: break-word` property breaks the word to next line when it doesn't find ample amount of space.