# Wrap a word without spaces in a div

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have a div that is of fixed width, 300px.  I have user inputed text that needs to go into the div.  The issue is, is that people are putting the word "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" into the div.  This causes the text to exceed the width of the div.  What I would like is for the text to wrap even if there is no spaces in the words.  Is there a way to do this with css?  I tried the css `white-space` property but it was not working.

If anyone has a solution or a point in the the right direction would be wonderful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to word wrap text in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Comment: Nice. Is this supported in all browsers? Awesome solution. :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this properly, with the current state of the art. Line breaking rules are complex and vary by language.

Using `word-wrap:break-word` or some of its va
riants arbitrarily breaks a string of characte
rs and almost certainly breaks the rules of th
e language and confuses people.