# Positioning image in github markdown table

Tags: css, github, gridview, markdown

I have some content which does not take up the entire column. so I was trying to postion an image to that side so that it saves some space.

[image: lesswidth image]

I tried checking for grid layouts or column layout in md but none of it has provided info on how to do it

This is what i am looking for

[image: expectation]

the code is @ [here](https://github.com/Co-Science/Cs-Web/blob/main/Sem%204/DE/day02to4-2021_05_04.md)

... thanks

Comment: I Think, this is might help!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603577/two-column-layout-with-markdown

Comment: thanks for the suggession @ishfaq. I had little knowledge in html table at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Markdown` table does not support cell merge by default, so you should use `HTML` table.
And in comment, you said

> "Even this time the image took only one row, ..."

in this case just use `rowspan`.

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>- Identifying cutomer needs (requirments)</td>
      <td rowspan="11">
        <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74305823/118094261-783e8280-b409-11eb-8f50-8ed0b304fef0.png" width="300"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- market analysis (requirements)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- defining goals (requirements)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Establishing functions (Prodct concept)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Task Specifications (Prodct concept)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Conceptualizatoin (Solution concept)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Evaluating Alternatives</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Emnodiment Design</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Analysis and Optimization</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Experiment</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>- Marketing</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

### EDIT

AS @tarleb said, using `<ul>...</ul>` tag can be more simple.

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <ul>
         <li>Identifying cutomer needs (requirments)</li>   
         <li>market analysis (requirements)</li>  
         <li>defining goals (requirements)</li> 
         <li>Establishing functions (Prodct concept)</li>  
         <li>Task Specifications (Prodct concept)</li> 
         <li>Conceptualizatoin (Solution concept)</li>   
         <li>Evaluating Alternatives</li> 
         <li>Emnodiment Design</li>
         <li>Analysis and Optimization</li>
         <li>Experiment</li>    
         <li>Marketing</li> 
       </ul>
     </td>
     <td>
       <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74305823/118094261-783e8280-b409-11eb-8f50-8ed0b304fef0.png" width="300"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: How about using one row, with the list in `<ul> ... </ul>` on the left and image on the right?

Comment: @tarleb That seems to be more simple and looks good. I edited my answer, thank you :)