# How to add line breaks in Grid View TemplateField

Tags: asp.net

This is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" HeaderStyle-Width="60%">                                                                 
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("Comments").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")%>  
</ItemTemplate>
```

This is not adding a line break due to which the grid is getting stretched. Please provide a solution.

Comment: Css  word-wrap is essay to use .Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1147889/795683

Comment: I have a textarea which takes max. 2000 characters.On displaying it in gridview ,it does not go to the next line and keeps on extending horizontally.

Comment: you can add a `p` tag and set `Eval("Comments")` in it, do post sample value of `Eval("Comments")` so it give us clear idea