# Prevent long text from overflowing

Tags: html, css

How do I break all words (inside the `<pre>`) that are too long that keep overflowing:

```
<pre>A paragraph is a group of words put together to form a group that is usually longer than a sentence. Paragraphs are often made up of several sentences. There are usually between three and eight sentences. Paragraphs can begin with an indentation (about five spaces), or by missing a line out, and then starting again. This makes it easier to see when one paragraph ends and another begins.</pre>
```

Comment: Just use the paragraph tag `<p>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to word wrap text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word-wrap and white-space to achieve the desired results. Like this:

```css
pre {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<pre>A paragraph is a group of words put together to form a group that is usually longer than a sentence. Paragraphs are often made up of several sentences. There are usually between three and eight sentences. Paragraphs can begin with an indentation (about five spaces), or by missing a line out, and then starting again. This makes it easier to see when one paragraph ends and another begins.
</pre>
```

**NOTE**: I have used css on  element that sets **white-space** to **pre-wrap** and **word-break** to **break-word**.